# Typescript 4: Temporary overriding of a prototype method

Tags: typescript, methods, instance, delete-operator

Next code runs on typescript 3.3.3 (on repl.it). It overrides or reverts to a prototype's method on every other call.

```
class Foo {
  foo () {
    this.foo = function() {
      console.log('instance call')
      delete this.foo // ⟵ Compilation problem with TS4 here
    }
    console.log('prototype call')
  }
}
const f = new Foo()
f.foo()
f.foo()
f.foo()
f.foo()
```

The output reads:

```
prototype call
instance call
prototype call
instance call
```

But this code does not compile on typescript 4. The delete line issues a "The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional." error.

Is there some way to fix that particular compilation problem?
Possibly with minor changes because I use this paradigm a lot.

Comment: You can always `// @ts-ignore` if you have good reason to such things..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript 4.0 added the restriction that [you may only `delete` properties that are optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#operands-for-delete-must-be-optional).  Since the `foo` property of `Foo` is required, you are not allowed to `delete` it.  The use case of deleting something from the instance which also exists in the prototype was presumably not considered, or not considered important enough.

---

One way to fix this in general is to make the `foo` method optional, like this:

```
class Foo {
  foo?() {
    this.foo = function () {
      console.log('instance call')
      delete this.foo
    }
    console.log('prototype call')
  }
}
const f = new Foo()
if (f.foo) f.foo()
if (f.foo) f.foo()
if (f.foo) f.foo()
if (f.foo) f.foo()
```

but this is probably **not** what you want to do since you know that `foo` will always exist somewhere in the inheritance chain.

---

Instead you can just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) in the `delete` statement to tell the compiler to treat `this` as if its `foo` property is optional:

```
class Foo {
  foo() {
    this.foo = function () {
      console.log('instance call')
      delete (this as Partial<Foo>).foo  
    }
    console.log('prototype call')
  }
}
const f = new Foo()
f.foo()
f.foo()
f.foo()
f.foo()
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgHID2ehRS8GIUUSAYlTQffQGacB+ABQBKWjx4AXABYBLKADp+NALxJeAV2DxJsqsCSjxEnvH1QqGCAoxUA5kIDks4FEkhtydBgyORdEyIAEwgrSWQZeSVOAIkAX1jTc0trWwdHGAAnKkkcgE8YL0xffxMEnnL6M1dJdSQ1YAgAd3ZOI1jZXkNeaKoxHuVRDq6hAc5+3qGeTu7eicHS+hnRufVJxcqSaDhEJABNaGMiRmZWDi5E9TaxbkDIxWV69S0dPQMjW8CGZKsbeycXG4PLtvCVLjwQmFkEJ7khmEgAAogTK6TAAHnOAD4RL1wUhKiZqhZfmknFkcvlCgxin5LgT8bEibUug1mq0qFM+OtYmMOYsiLzOQLuUQEnEgA)

Comment: In the first fix, one can replace `if (f.foo) f.foo()` by `f.foo!()` when it always exists. But the second fix seems more efficient.